# identify directory named for the most recent date

Tags: bash

I name output folders for the date that I run a program on. So, I have the following folders in my directory:

```
2011.05.18
2011.06.30
2011.07.07
2011.07.27
2011.08.03
```

How can I automatically identify the most recent one from the command line (e.g. so that I can make a symbolic link to files in it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LATEST=`ls -d1 | sort | tail -1`
```

If you have other files/directories besides the `yyyy.mm.dd` directories, then this would be better:

```
LATEST=`ls -d1 [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9] | sort | tail -1`
```

Comment: I have many other files/ directories, this returns a filename

Comment: @Abe: do you mean you have files in the same directory with names like `xxxx.xx.xx`? (I've changed my answer to only match files/directories with digits in.)

Comment: yes, I have a file named 'vcmax.model.bug that were being selected

Comment: even though that file is in a subdirectory

Comment: @Abe: are you sure? `????.??.??` won't match `vcmax.model.bug`. I changed my answer from `????.??.??` to the current answer in case you had files/directories named for example `abcd.ef.ghij`.

Comment: @Abe: ah, I know what you mean. It's listing files *inside* the directories. Answer updated to include `-d`. I should have added that in the first place :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
MOSTRECENT=`ls -1 ????.??.?? | sort -r | head -1`
```

or with no use of `ls`

```
MOSTRECENT=`for F in ????.??.??; do echo $F; done | sort -r | head -1`
```

Comment: Not easy to type on a playbook.

Comment: @Jack the first one returns a filename, the second one works as expected

Comment: As I have just realised, the `-d` options needs to be used with `ls`, or `ls` will list the *contents* of the directories, which messes up the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
for dir in ????.??.?? ; do LATEST=$dir ; done
```

(Doesn't need `ls`.)

Answer (score 0):

Get a directory listing ordered by modification time, and choose the topmost;
`ls -t|head -n 1`

Comment: That assumes the modification times correspond to the directory names.  It can break if you go back an edit a file in a directory from a month ago, for example.